# Is this considered O(1) space complexity (python)

Tags: python, string, algorithm, big-o, space-complexity

I was working through the following problem:

> Implement a function for reversing the words in a string. Your
>   function should use O(1) space. Eg: "I love tacos" => "tacos love I"

This is the code I came up with in Python:

```
def reverseSentence(sentence):
    sentence =sentence.split()
    for i in range((len(sentence)/2)):
        sentence[i], sentence[len(sentence)-1-i] = sentence[len(sentence)-1-i], sentence[i]
    return " ".join(sentence)

print reverseSentence("I love tacos") 
# Outputs: tacos love I
```

Ultimately I am concerned if this is considered O(1) space complexity because:

**1)** I use `sentence = sentence.split()`. Sentence is not being changed in place, rather I am changing sentence and assigning it back to the variable `sentence`.

**2)** I swap using pythons `a,b = b,a`. How is this perceived in terms of space complexity?

Comment: This task isn't actually possible in a language with immutable strings, like Python.

Comment: You **can't** change the sentence in place. Strings are immutable in Python.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation,  I figured that it would be impossible in python.

Comment: The trade-off, of course, is that Python allows you to do lovely things like this inexpensively in terms of typing and thinking, like so: `' '.join(reversed(sentence.split()))` ;)

Comment: If you're just doing it for learning purposes, you could solve the version of the problem where `sentence` is a list of characters instead of a string.

Comment: Just building the new string will take O(N) space, not O(1).   You could print the words in reverse order *without* building a new string, using O(1) space.